# Is it possible to create two markers for one position?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Iam working on a google maps implementation, which is basically a map of an vacation park. Here I need to show houses which are located there. I have create the google maps with the houses as markers but the customer wants it like this:
[image]

So basically there needs to be a circle on it which prints the number/ `id` given like this:

```
 var locations = [
    [{id: 1,  lat: 51.52382330377623,  lng:  5.137980404243535,   content: 'Kids Jungalow A'}],
    [{id: 2,  lat: 51.52365641932812,  lng:  5.138034048423833,   content: 'Kids Jungalow B'}],
    [{id: 3,  lat: 51.523512898213674, lng:  5.138157430038518,   content: 'Kids Jungalow C'}],
    [{id: 4,  lat: 51.523356025780366, lng:  5.138221803054876,   content: 'Kids Jungalow D'}],
    [{id: 5,  lat: 51.52321917917386,  lng:  5.13836664234168,    content: 'Kids Jungalow E'}],
    [{id: 6,  lat: 51.52306230572866,  lng:  5.138559761390752,   content: 'Kids Jungalow F'}],
]
```

Is it maybe possible to append a div to the markers? That I make an html marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a marker with custom HTML in them. Take a look at [Rich Marker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker) library or [Marker With Label](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) library (you can style to look like bubble with number)

Both libraries leverage [google.maps.OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple), which is the prototype of class you can reuse to create your own custom markers. There are no limitations to what's in the marker, you can display your own HTML inside, images, svg...Just take a look at the example code inside `USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd` function from the above referenced site. You can create any structure you want inside, so you can have for example something like this:

```
MyOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div'); //marker container div
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  var img = document.createElement('img'); //house image icon
  img.src = "myimages/house.png";
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  var circle = document.createElement('div'); //house image icon
  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  //..other circle styles/css classes to style the div in the shape of circle
  circle.innerHTML = this.number_inside_circle; //here you can set number inside the circle
  div.appendChild(circle);

  this.div_ = div;

  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Marker Labels:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels
e.g.:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels

However the marker only accepts a single character label by default. The [Marker Clusterer](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html) can do this, or there are some other solutions in a [support ticket](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8578).